# Error messsage "Error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070001."

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

This is the error that we get when so many users go to the same page simultaneously. We are getting this error in the global.asax file. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: And what exactly is happening in global.asax? Can you show us some code?

Comment: We are catching the application errors in Application_Error() event handler. When we get an error on the page that is not handled, it will go into this event handler. And all we are doing in the handler is sending an email if server.GetLastError.InnerException() is not null.